# SetWindowTextW() helper function in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, floating-point, char

I wonder whether there is a "better way" to supply SetWindowText "text" argument than this code:

```
wchar_t buffer[20];
Measures10nm.CIE_L = 100.3456f;
Measures10nm.CIE_a = -9.34f;
Measures10nm.CIE_b = -56.56f;
swprintf_s(buffer, 20, L"%.2f", Measures10nm.CIE_L);    
SetWindowTextW(hEditCIE_L, buffer);
swprintf_s(buffer, 20, L"%.2f", Measures10nm.CIE_a);
SetWindowTextW(hEditCIE_a, buffer);
swprintf_s(buffer, 20, L"%.2f", Measures10nm.CIE_b);
SetWindowTextW(hEditCIE_b, buffer);
```

I tried to experiment with a function that I could supply a float to and who would return a wchar_t, since that's the type of argument SetTextWindow() requires but I have not been "successful" at it. I'm not even sure this is possible, technically, after all the time I experimented with various coding? Ideally, what I'd like to use is a function like this :

```
SetTextWindow(hEdit, floatToWchar_t(Measures10nm.CIE_L));
```

But I have not been able to code such a function?
I experimented with something along these lines :

```
wchar_t floatToWchar_t(float x)
{
wchar_t buffer[20];
swprintf_s(buffer, 20, L"%f", x);
return buffer;
}
```

But that does not work because wchar_t is an array, I suppose. I thought about using a pointer to the array but I can't conceptualize clearly how to do it.

Any help is appreciated. Please excuse the newbie question...

Comment: You can make `buffer` static (`static wchar_t buffer[20]`), but this puts restrictions on use of the returned value that are not obvious to the caller. (There are also possible threading issues as well.)

Comment: There's [std::to_wstring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) which does, what your final piece of code attempts. It returns a `std::wstring`, so you're going to have to use its `.c_str()` member to get a pointer you can pass into `SetWindowTextW`.

Comment: possible write function with such signature `BOOL SetWinTxt(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ PCWSTR format, ...);`

Comment: In C++ the function signature should probably be something like `template <typename... Args> void FormatWindowText(HWND hWnd, wchar_t const* format, Args... args)`. Unlike the C-style variadic function, the function template preserves type information, making it possible for an implementation to verify, at compile time, that the number and types of arguments match the format string.

Comment: and `template <typename... Args> void FormatWindowText(HWND hWnd, wchar_t const* format, Args... args)` generate multiple functions in code, unlike `BOOL SetWinTxt(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ PCWSTR format, ...);` - single function

Comment: And ICF shrink-wraps those functions back into a single block of object code. Even if it cannot, any bug that can be detected at compile time **should** be detected at compile time. Particularly true with variadic C functions, where the compiler doesn't do **any** type checking. At all. And there's no way to verify correctness at runtime. And practically every bug leads to an exploitable defect.

Answer (score 2):

We're talking C++ here so forget about character arrays and use `std::wstring` and C++ streams.

```cpp
#include <sstream>

std::wstringstream ss; // String-based stream.
float f = 3.14; // Our float.
ss << f; // Output the float to the stream.
SetWindowTextW(hWnd, ss.str().c_str()); // Covert to a `wchar_t` zero-terminated string.
```

You can easily wrap this in a function.

```cpp
void SetWindowFloat(HWND hWnd, float f);
```

If you need to modify how the float is converted to a string, take a look at [iomanip](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip).

Comment: `std::wostringstream` would be better than `std::wstringstream`.  `std::to_wstring()` would be even better (unless you need custom formatting).

Comment: @rveerd // I had the same reaction as you, "This is c++" and "strings" should make my life easier, but I could get around the "screen of smoke" of "LPCWSTR lpString".  I experimented quite a bit with std::stringstream but it can't be passed directly to any Windows calls. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Modify for wstring ....

```
std::wstring floatToWideString(float x)
{
   wchar_t buffer[20];
   swprintf_s(buffer, 20, L"%f", x);
   return buffer;
}
```

Then

```
void SetWindowText(HWND hwnd, const std::wstring& s)
{
   SetWindowText(hwnd, s.c_str());
}


SetWindowText(hwnd, floatToWideString(3.1415f));
```

... but with all your calls to SetWindowText to the same hwnd, you're going to overwrite what's there....it's not like it is a line buffer.

Update:
Also, if you get so inclined to use use MFC, or just to use `<atlstr.h>`, there is a CString class that has a (LPCTSTR) cast operator.

Something like:

```
CStringW floatToWideCString(float x)
    {
       CStringW s;
       s.Format(_T("%f"), x);
       return s;
    }

SetWindowText(hwnd, floatToWideCString(3.14));
```

Comment: There is also the function std::to_wstring() which will convert the value to a wstring. Haven't used it enough to know if you can supply formatting to it for the number of places after the decimal.

Comment: No, `to_wstring()` does not allow you to customize the formatting, it is basically just a wrapper for `std::swprintf(L"%f")`

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson // First, thank you so much for your solution. I'm curious why you you need the string length in your SetWindowText() call? I thought the call only required two arguments. Just curious :-)

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Working from memory on a machine without WINAPI installed and didn't look it up. Yes, only needs the one argument.

Comment: @RogerBreton I guess I was falsely remembering an extra argument. The HDC functions `TextOut` and `DrawText` have some length arguments, but `SetWindowText` does not.